# List of same model MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a model enrollment that have a list of components that have a list of subcomponents. This is what i have:

```
public class Enrollment
    {
       ...
       public virtual int ClassroomId { get; set; }
        public virtual Classroom Classroom { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Components> Components { get; set; }
       }
public class Component
    {
       ...
        public virtual int EnrollmentId { get; set; }   
        public virtual Enrollment Enrollment{ get; set; }
        public virtual List<Subcomponent> Subcomponents { get; set; }
}
public class Subcomponent
    {
       ...
        public virtual int ComponentId { get; set; }   
        public virtual Component Component{ get; set; }

public virtual List<Subcomponent> Subcomponent { get; set; } (???)
}
```

**The user needs to be able to create subsubcomponents and so on, as much as he wants.** For example, the enrollment Matematics have a component Test that have a subcomponent Group1 that can have a subsubcomponent Question 1 and a subsubsubcomponent Question 1.1 and so on.
I have this create methods on the Subcomponent controller:

```
public ActionResult CreateMoreSubcomponents(int id)
        {
            var x = db.Subcomponents.FirstOrDefault(e => e.SubcomponentId == id);

            if (x == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            var subcomponent = new Subcomponent()
            {
                ComponentId = x.ComponentId,
                SubcomponentId = x.SubcomponentId
            };

            return View("CreateMoreSubcomponents", subcomponent);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult CreateMoreSubcomponents(Subcomponent subcomponent)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Subcomponents.Add(subcomponent);
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction(...);
            }


            return View(subcomponent);
        }
```

Note that this code may be all wrong, this was just a way i tried to do. The question is how can i do it? Am i close to the solution or not so close and if so how is it possible to do what i want? Thanks

**EDIT:**
I changed the code since it needs the componentId anyways. In this way it gives me an error on `db.SaveChanges();`

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Subcomponents_dbo.Components_ComponentId". The conflict occurred in database "SGPContext-20160719133511", table "dbo.Components", column 'ComponentId'. The statement has been terminated

Comment: What problems are you having?

Comment: @StephenMuecke On db.SaveChanges(); it gives an error, "An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code" Error updating entrys(not in english, don't know if this is the correct translation)

Comment: You need to catch the exception and inspect the inner details to determine what the problem is.

Comment: It gives this error: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Subcomponents_dbo.Components_ComponentId". The conflict occurred in database "SGPContext-20160719133511", table "dbo.Components", column 'ComponentId'. The statement has been terminated. I updated the question and the code but the error stays, don't know what do i need to change now.

Comment: You have not given enough information. What is the value of `subcomponent.ComponentId` in the POST method. Is there a record in your `Component` table with that `ComponentId`

Comment: But if you creating a `Subcomponent` where the parent in another `Subcomponent` (as opposed to a `Component`) then you need a hierarchical data structure for your `Subcomponent` model

Comment: yes the parent of the subcomponent would be another subcomponent